# When updating multiple records in Rails how to remove successfully updated ones from the list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I followed this tutorial (http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple-revised) and built a form to update multiple records at a time. The problem is, when I hit update, the form will reload and will also show the records that don't have errors.

I need to remove the successfully saved records from the list and show only the ones with errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the records that don't have errors are being saved, so perhaps you can just hide them with jQuery.

Do the records with errors all have a class assigned to them by rails such as "error"?

If so, then you add a class to the divs containing each record like this...

```
<div class="record_container">
  record goes here
</div>
```

and then hide all records and then unhide any the ones with the error class by putting this at the bottom of your HTML view:

```
<script>
  $(".record_container").hide();
  $(".error").hide();
</script>
```